# Is there a best practice regarding PDF files on website?

Tags: web-application, pdf

When a website supplies a PDF there are two options for how a user might interact with it:

- View it in browser
- Download it

As the host of these files is there a security advantage one way or the other? Is it safer for the users if we default the functionality one way?

Comment: You can force a file to be downloaded but you cant force it to be viewed in a web browser

Comment: I don't think either way puts you as the host at extra risk as it would just be the content stream that changes, you still host it. As a user I would expect slightly higher risk in moving a file to my machine rather than viewing it, either way the content does end up on your users's client.

Comment: Just one precision, if you use CSP, it may prevent the view in the browser.

Comment: chrome uses an internal PDF renderer, which they upkeep, whereas adobe software is often dated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's generally safer to force-download files, than to view them directly in the browser. However, in the case of PDFs, the PDF viewers in Firefox and Chrome are probably safer and more up-to-date than the ones from Adobe or Foxit

Assuming you let users upload PDFs:

1. Store them in a database, and not on the file system, unless you know exactly what you're doing (see Path Traversal attacks)
2. Serve them from a different domain name (like googleusercontent.com vs google.com), to avoid cookie theft/clobbering on your main domain
3. Validate on upload. Check that size is the same as reported size. Check that filename looks ok. Virus scan. Use a PDF library to strip embedded JavaScript (you could try Apache PDFBox)

Comment: thanks for sharing these useful security recommendations